# Unmerge specific group in multiindex groupby dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

My dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"TEAM":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2], "ID":[1,1,2,2,8,4,5], "TYPE":["A","B","A","B","A","A","A"], "VALUE":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
df = df.groupby(["TEAM", "ID", "TYPE"]).sum()
```

```
              VALUE
TEAM ID TYPE
1    1  A         1
        B         1
     2  A         1
        B         1
2    4  A         1
     5  A         1
     8  A         1
```

In the above I would like to ungroup `TEAM` in the same level as `ID`

Expected output

```
              VALUE
TEAM ID TYPE
1    1  A         1
        B         1
1    2  A         1
        B         1
2    4  A         1
2    5  A         1
2    8  A         1
```

Comment: Are you asking to have different *representation* of the dataframe? If so, I'm afraid you need to do so manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat columns `TEAM` and `ID` on same level, then you can create a column by combining these two columns and group on this new column.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"TEAM":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2], "ID":[1,1,2,2,8,4,5], "TYPE":["A","B","A","B","A","A","A"], "VALUE":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
df["TEAM_ID"] = df["TEAM"].astype(str) + "_" + df["ID"].astype(str)
df = df[["TEAM_ID", "TYPE", "VALUE"]].groupby(["TEAM_ID", "TYPE"]).sum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              VALUE
TEAM_ID TYPE       
1_1     A         1
        B         1
1_2     A         1
        B         1
2_4     A         1
2_5     A         1
2_8     A         1
```

and then split values when to be used

OR

```py
df = df.groupby(["TEAM_ID", "TYPE"]).sum()
```

to keep repeated `TEAM` and `ID` values.

```
              TEAM  ID  VALUE
TEAM_ID TYPE                 
1_1     A        1   1      1
        B        1   1      1
1_2     A        1   2      1
        B        1   2      1
2_4     A        2   4      1
2_5     A        2   5      1
2_8     A        2   8      1
```